# Google Play Realtime Developer Notification for one time products not working

Tags: in-app-billing, google-play-console

I utilize realtime developer notification to process the purchases within my app. For subscriptions this works flawless, but for one time products I never received a message.

Working:

- Subscription message
- Test message

Not working:

- One time product message

I use the "Test card - always approves" so the purchase came through. Even if I acknowlege it on the frontend, I do not receive any notification on the backend, but I should get one according to the [docu](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/rtdn-reference#one-time)

What is wrong here?

Comment: Had the same problem. This is the answer to your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65029988/android-real-time-developer-notification-for-one-time-purchase-is-half-working

Google documentation is really not clear about that.

Comment: Wow, this is such a stupid implementation. Why would they allow EVERYTHING on the backend but the one time purchases still have to processed on front end. No use at all...Thank you

Comment: Exactly. It is very frustrating for us too. But they must have some reasons why they do it like that. iOS notifications system for in-app purchases has the same behavior.